# How to get Android Device Density Unit

Tags: java, eclipse, appium

I want to click on certain point(x,y) on an android device. But as i figured it out I need to get density unit of that device to equilibrate my point according to different devices.

I wonder how can I get ths density unit to use in my code.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for posting. Please look through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get density for the device

```
 getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```